# How to make pluggable static classes

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, static-classes

I know how to make pluggable things in c#. Define an Interface, `Activator.CreateInstance(<class>)`, etc. Or I can have a code path that explicitly creates an instance of the plugged class. Many ways.

But what if the service I want to make pluggable is static (I know I could refactor so that it's not but that's not the point of the question)

Concrete example. I have a class that provides disk I/O abstraction (Read File, List Directory,....). Now I want different implementations of this abstraction that serves up files from , say, a real FS, a database.

Based on Olivier Jacot-Descombes reply, I will have a `FileSystem` class (that is real) like this

```
public static class FileSystem
{
    static IFSImplemenation s_imple;
    static FileSystem()
    {
        if(<some system setting>)
            // converted to singleton instead of static
            s_imple = new OldFileSystem() 
        else
            s_imple = new DbFileSystem();
    }

    public static byte[] ReadFile(string path)
    {
        return s_imple.ReadFile(path);
    }

    ...
}
```

To reiterate - I have a large body of code that I dont want to change so it was important to keep the calling signature the same - this solution achieves that

Comment: If you want abstractions and design-by-contract, etc., then you want to be using instances and not static methods.  You knowing this doesn't change the fact that using `static` constructs for this purpose is totally the wrong way to go.

Comment: You really, *really* want to look at dependency injection; you're gaining the ability to swap out implementations, but it's not easy at all, more than likely requires a recompile of the consumer (dependency injection doesn't require a recompile) and isn't testable at all.

Comment: @casperOne I thought all the DI systems we based around instantianted classes

Comment: Yes, but the DI implementations do the instantiation for you, usually through code compiled on-the-fly or reflection (usually the former) an based on patterns (finding the mapping between the interface and the concrete type).  If your classes are all in libraries and use the contracts, the contracts don't change, and the libraries don't need to be recompiled, only the place where you set up DI.  Everything else remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your static class as facade for non-static implementations

```
public static class DB
{
    private static IDbInterface _implementation;

    public static void SetImplementation(IDbInterface implementation)
    {
        _implementation = implementation;
    }

    public static Customer GetCustomerByID(int custId)
    {
        return _implementation.GetCustomerByID(custId);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this. Actually i think having the redirection done in static constructor of the class (based on some environment settings is better) - then no changes to calling code at all

Answer (score 5):

You can't, and that's a limitation of the type system in .NET and most object-oriented systems/languages.

The reason being that "pluggable things" (as you refer to them) require [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming) in order to be effective.

You define a contract (an interface, in .NET-speak), and then you *implement* that contract.  Your system only ever deals *with the contract*.

Static members are not polymorphic in .NET, so you can never get them to implement a contract.

For your example of disk I/O abstraction, you wouldn't create a static class for this, you'd create an interface, and implement the interface, passing around the interface.

Of course, the benefits of using an interface are that it's easier to test both sides of the implementation of your contract:

- Where the contract is a client, you can mock the interface easily and pass the mock to the consumers of the contract (this is where you might start thinking about [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection))
- You can test the implementation separately from the rest of your system.

In the case of your disk I/O abstraction, for everything that calls your contract, you would never have to worry about *actually* touching the file system, you simply have to make the contract behave (through proper mock setup) as if it *were* touching the file system.

If you have an existing service that is exposed through static members, and you want the ability to swap that out with another implementation, then you'll have to do the following:

- Create an abstraction (contract/abstract type) which defines the operations on your service.
- Create an implementation that forwards the calls from the instance of the implementation of the abstraction to the static methods.
- Rewire all of the static calls to the service with instances of the implementation.  At this point, you really *must* use dependency injection of some sort; if you don't, you're just creating the concrete implementation at the call site, and that's pretty much the same (you'd have to change every call site again if you wanted to use another implementation).

Comment: I full understand contracts, polymorphism etc. pluggable things dont need polymorphism. By pluggable I mean runtime replaceable implementations of services. As I said in my question  - I know that using Interfaces is the right way to go , but thats not the point of the question. I want to see if people have ideas for making a runtime replaceable static

Comment: @pm100 You seem to miss the point of the answer, the only way that you can swap one thing out for another is by providing another implementation of an interface/abstract class.  You *can't* swap something out that's static, it's just not possible in .NET.  The fundamental answer to your question is "no", and this answer is my best attempt to explain why.

Comment: @pm100 Added more to indicate what to do if you want to make a static service a pluggable service, but I feel it still doesn't give you the answer you *want*, unfortunately (but I can't change how .NET works in this way).

Answer (score 1):

Static classes are not "pluggable".  If you want to be able to swap it out, you need to refactor it to use interfaces that you can inject.

Some classes have a static `Current` or `Default` parameter, such as ServiceLocator.  You then use `ServiceLocator.Current` to access the current `IServiceLocator` in a static context.

You can take this a little further and hide the `Current` object.  While I don't recommend doing this, it will prevent the need to refactor all of your code.  However, the maintenance is much higher with this method, as `Foo` does not implement `IFoo`.

Suppose you have a static class `Foo`

```
static class Foo
{
    public static string GetBar() { return "Bar"; }
}
```

You could make an interface `IFoo`

```
interface IFoo
{
    string GetBar();
}
```

Now change your class Foo to the following

```
static class Foo 
{
    private static IFoo _foo;

    public static void SetFoo(IFoo foo) { _foo = foo; }

    public static string GetBar() { return _foo.GetBar(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make you static class residenting in host application and being actually a factory: returning implementation provided by a plugin by interface.